# Black Dashboard: loading another HTML file height problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to use [Black Dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard) for my Admin Panel. As I click on my Nav Icons, another HTML file is being loaded into a `div` tag. The problem is that when I do this using JavaScript, the loaded file is not in full height and appears with a vertical scroll bar.
you can see the main html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b023e3b1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white">
            <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
               <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="posts"">
                         <i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i>
                         <p>Posts</p>
                      </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel"> 
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="card" id="main-content">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <link href="black-dashboard.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="black-dashboard.js?v=1.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script> 
        document.getElementById("posts").onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="newpost.html" ></object>';
        };
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The `newpost.html` file that I want to load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53b023e3b1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="black-dashboard.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>new post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">          
        <div class="card-header">
            Nav Item Title
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                   <!-- simple form here -->
                </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="black-dashboard.js?v=1.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried different CSS solutions including using `height: 100%` for parent and child elements and `felx` but nothing seems to work. You can see the screen shot of the result below:
[image: The result]

Any help would be really appreciated <3

UPDATE: The problem was somehow related to my editor. I was using Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your css:

```
.card {
    height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

And where I have `40px` substitute the height needed for your Dashboard header.

Comment: I had tried the Height solutions before but I gave it a try again and no luck. Thanks.

Comment: So what happens? Can you check in the inspector if the rule is applied?

Comment: The problem is not CSS related. it's somehow related to the way html is being loaded and a plugin named "perfect-scrollbar" that the dashboard uses. I think it's also interfering with my jQuery library and that's why I can't load the file through jQuery. Still working on it.

Comment: Is the stylesheet even loaded? It looks like the path isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to use Black Dashboard for your  Admin Panel ;

link href="../assets/css/black-dashboard.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet"

Comment: The code is already in the file: <script src="black-dashboard.js?v=1.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: That is the .js file.. you need the .css file as well

Comment: @Esger that file is also included. please read the codes provided in the questions you intend to answer properly in order to prevent down votes. good luck!